# Menu Icons is not showing up in Xamarin.Android App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin mobile app development.
I got a task to add navigation menu with their titles and Icons.

I am doing Code based UI for development, and here is the below code where I create navigation Menu.

```
public MainPage ()
    {
        BindingContext = new MainViewModel(this);
        this.Children.Add(new FirstTab() {Icon= "firsttab.png", Title="First Tab" });
        this.Children.Add(new SecondTab() {Icon= "secondtab.png", Title="Second Tab" });
        this.Children.Add(new ThirdTab() {Icon= "thirdtab.png", Title="Third Tab" });

        this.CurrentPageChanged += MainPage_CurrentPageChanged;
        this.Title = this.CurrentPage.Title;
    }
```

I am getting navigation menu with all the three tabs but only with their `Titles` Icons are not showing up.

I also read the [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77100/menu-icon-and-title-not-showing-on-uwp-works-on-android-and-ios) blog but no result.

Can anyone help me how to get this done or where I am doing wrong?
Thank You

Comment: Is MainPage your TabbedPage?

Comment: @hichame.yessou yeah Inherited from TabbedPage.

Comment: What is your Xamarin.Forms version?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT 2.3.3.175

Comment: Update your Xamarin.Forms to the latest version, it works fine on my side.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT can you please show the sample with the new version and post that as an answer?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? – York Shen - MSFT

Answer (score 2):

> Menu Icons is not showing up in Xamarin.Android App

Update your `Xamarin.Forms` to `2.4.0.282` or later, the icon will show up.

In my code:

```
MainPage = new TabbedPage1();

...

public partial class TabbedPage1 : TabbedPage
{
    public TabbedPage1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Children.Add(new ContentPage() { Icon = "icon.png", Title = "First Tab" });
        this.Children.Add(new ContentPage() { Icon = "icon.png", Title = "Second Tab" });
        this.Children.Add(new ContentPage() { Icon = "icon.png", Title = "Third Tab" });
    }
}
```

My `Xamarin.Forms` version is 2.4.0.282, [Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze64r.png).